# How to Path correction in ROS1

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning

When controlling robot movement using angular velocity and linear velocity, deviations from the expected path often occur due to external factors，for example To make a wheeled robot move in a circular path, I provide it with angular velocity and linear velocity. However, over time, the path tends to deviate. Therefore, I would like to inquire if there are packages available in ROS or other keywords to reference. Currently, I intend to subscribe to the 'odom' topic to monitor the robot's status, and if the deviation is too large, I plan to perform corrections. I wonder if this approach is feasible. I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, over time, the path tends to deviate.

This is how open loop systems behave and the drift happens not only due to **external** factors but could be due to internal factors.

> if the deviation is too large, I plan to perform corrections

This is where feedback and a close-loop system comes into picture. To know the deviation you will need to know the **true state** (ground truth) of the robot.

> I wonder if this approach is feasible

This approach is feasible given that you have a means of finding out true state/ ground truth to calculate the deviation.

### Shortcut

In ROS, you get the ground truth via a topic **/gazebo/model_states**

### Long answer

Finding the true position of the robot is known as the **localization problem**  in robotics and it involves sensors. There is a multitude of approaches to solve the localization problem and many different types of sensors are involved. If you are interested, a good starting point would be [**Probabilistic Robotics** <sup>S. Thrun</sup>](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/)

Comment: thank you for your reply! !
So to sum up, first of all, the actual position of the robot must be positioned in order to effectively correct the path.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Please, feel free to accept the answer if it helped.